# Enumerate NSDictionary with keys and objects, PHP style

Tags: objective-c, enumeration

I know you can Enumerate the keys or values of `NSMutableDictionary` using `NSEnumerator`. Is it possible to do both together? I'm looking for something similar to the PHP `foreach` enumerator like:

```
foreach ($dictionary as $key => $value);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701126/get-the-array-index-in-for-statement-in-objective-c/3701165#3701165

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Perhaps look into NSDictionary's method:

```
enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))
```

If you're not familiar with blocks in C/Objective-C, this is a good tutorial: http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/

Comment: I saw this and liked what I saw, but blocks seem to be 10.6 & 4.0 iOS only. Still supporting 3.1.3 in my app.

Answer (score 35):

```
NSDictionary* d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"obj1",@"key1",
                                                           @"obj2",@"key2",
                                                           @"obj3",@"key3",
                                                           @"obj4",@"key4",nil];

for (id key in [d allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@",key,[d objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
keytest[7880:a0f] key3 - obj3
keytest[7880:a0f] key1 - obj1
keytest[7880:a0f] key4 - obj4
keytest[7880:a0f] key2 - obj2
```

Comment: One thing: Using fast enumeration on an `NSDictionary` already iterates the keys, so the `[d allKeys]` is unnecessary.

Comment: I think the blocks are nicer, but this is what I ended up doing since I can't use blocks in my iphone app.

Comment: yeah, blocks are the future but sometimes we have to live in the past

Answer (score 9):

Now much easier:

```
for (NSString * key in dict)
{
    id/* or your type */ value = dict[key];
    ...
}
```

Comment: This response doesn't answer the question. The OP was looking for a way to enumerate keys and values together. This approach only enumerates keys, and requires an additional lookup to obtain the value associated with each key.