# Display each item in an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdictionary

I am trying to display each item in NSDictionary. I have tried using a for loop but that didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerate NSDictionary with keys and objects, PHP style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775507/enumerate-nsdictionary-with-keys-and-objects-php-style)

Comment: If this doesn't get closed as a duplicate, alanvabraham, could you please explain what for-loop you tried using and how it failed to work?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try this code

```
for(NSString *key in [dict allKeys]) {
  NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: Better to add key in NSLog as well. You can do - ` NSLog(@"%@ : %@",key, [dict objectForKey:key]); `

Comment: Since this answer was written, new syntax has become available. You can now do  `NSLog(@"%@", dict[key]);` if you prefer..

Answer (score 35):

What about

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [myDictionary description]);
```

Seems to work for me...

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and is very useful for debugging.

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [theJSON JSONValue];

```
NSLog(@"dictionary data %@",jsonDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to save it on NSString you can use

```
NSMutableString *stringUserInfo = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSString *aKey in dictionary.allKeys)
    [stringUserInfo appendFormat:@"%@ : %@\n",aKey,[dictionary valueForKey:aKey]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*Try this simple example:

//.h file

@interface DictionaryClass : NSObject
{
    NSDictionary *dict;
}

-(void) intialiseDictionary;

-(void) displayDictonary;

-------------------------------------------------------
//.m file
#import "DictionaryClass.h"

@implementation DictionaryClass

-(void) intialiseDictionary

{

    dict = @{@"key1":@"object1",@"key2":@"object2",@"key3":@"object3",@"key4":@"object4"};

}

-(void) displayDictonary

{
    for(NSString *keys in dict)
    {
        NSLog(@"\n Dictionary object = %@",[dict objectForKey:keys]);

    }

}

@end
-------------------------------------------------------

//main function

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DictionaryClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{
    @autoreleasepool

    {
        DictionaryClass *obj = [[DictionaryClass alloc]init];

        [obj intialiseDictionary];
        [obj displayDictonary];
    }
    return 0;
}*
```

Answer (score -3):

i think you can print NSDictionary using

### NSDictionary *dic;

NSLog (@"nsdic = %@", dic);

Hope its help.